# How can I check versions of buildscript plugins on Gradle?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I want to know the version of the gradle plugin programmatically so I can check it from a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "buildscript" property from Project interface to access the configurations and dependencies of the buildScript, as follows:

```groovy
apply plugin: com.netflix.gradle.plugins.packaging.SystemPackagingPlugin

buildscript {
  ext {
      ospackagePluginVersion = '4.9.3'
  }
  repositories {
      jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
      classpath "com.netflix.nebula:gradle-ospackage-plugin:${ospackagePluginVersion}"
  }
}

println "Build script dependencies: "
buildscript.getConfigurations().getByName("classpath").getDependencies().each {
  Dependency dep ->
      println "Dependency : name=$dep.name in version : $dep.version"
      // do something with Dependency instance..
}
```

This will output:

```
> Configure project :
Build script dependencies: 
Dependency : name=gradle-ospackage-plugin in version : 4.9.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `buildscript.configurations.classpath.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies` instead if you need to see the effective version of a plugin that uses a dynamic version like `6.+`. Something like the below:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.diffplug.spotless' version '6.+'
}

project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.each {
    println("Plugin: name=${it.moduleGroup}, version=${it.moduleVersion}")
}
```

This will display the actual resolved version, `6.25.0`(as of now), instead of just `6.+`.

```
> Configure project :
Plugin: name=com.diffplug.spotless, version=6.25.0
```